# How do I delete a bookmark folder in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I open the Bookmarks manager with ctrl+shift+B, then right-click on the bookmark folder I wanna get rid of, and click Delete, but nothing happens.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying should work. At least I can do it on my side.

It might mean that your bookmark database is damaged. You can try to regenerate it following these steps :

1. If not already done, display the menu bar (right click in the top section of Firefox window and check the appropriate checkbox - useless on a Mac)
2. Just in case, backup your bookmarks (Bookmarks > Show all bookmarks > icon or menu to "save" or "backup")
3. Go to Help menu > Troubleshooting information and open the profile folder
4. Close all Firefox windows
5. In the profile folder, rename the file "places.sqlite" to "BU_places.sqlite"
6. Re-open Firefox and try again to delete the bookmark folder
7. If you could successfully delete it, you can now delete the BU_places.sqlite, as you might have noticed that Firefox has generated a new one.